# Folder missmatch with docker compose and deploying to heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file which looks like this

```
version: '3'

services:

  banana:
    image: &banana_version recruiter-1912/banana:20.8.1
    build:
      context: platform
      dockerfile: banana/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      PORT: 8000
      MN_VERSION: *banana_version
    volumes:
      - ./platform/banana:/banana
```

With this file structure:

```
- platform/
  - banana/
    - Dockerfile
    - requirements.txt
    - banana/
      -seemingly unimportant files-
- docker-compose.yml
```

And i am trying to deploy this service to Heroku.

I do this by doing `heroku container:push web` but for that i `cd` into the `platform/banana` directory.

When i try to push the container i get an error
`COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder648546726/banana/requirements.txt: no such file or directory`

```
FROM python:3.7.7-slim

COPY banana/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /banana
WORKDIR /banana

CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker banana.main:app
```

I can deploy this to heroku if i change `COPY banana/requirements.txt .` to `COPY requirements.txt .` BUT then my docker-compose build will not work due to the same no such file or directory error.

How do i make it so i can both deploy to heroku and docker-compose build locally without needing to change the file path in dockerfile every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the context to ., like this:

`context: .`

It means your context is the current working directory.

and change

`COPY banana/requirements.txt .`

to

`COPY platform/banana/requirements.txt .`

Comment: The context change worked, Thanks!


I did do:
`context: ./platform/banana`
since `COPY platform/banana/requirements.txt .` wouldn't work with heroku